# Show values from an Array in nouislider's tooltip

Tags: arrays, tooltip, angular5, nouislider

I'm making an angular 5 app and use nouislider in it. I'm trying to use the slider so the user can select values from an array. For example: `myArray = ['First Option', 'Second option', 'Third', ...]`. I've put the range of the slider from 0 to myArray.length-1. So that, 0 is for 'First', 1 for 'Second', ...And I need the tooltip to show 'First', etc. I've tried :

```
   ...
   format: {
   to: function ( value ) {
   return this.myArray[value];
   },...
```

But I just got an error:

> Cannot read property myArray of undefined

When I console.log(myArray) before the noUiSlider.create(slider, ... It shows but inside the noUiSlider it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the `to` formatting function, `this` is different then it is where you create the slider. You could change it to `yourSlider.myArray....` to keep using the same context.